# Server-Sent Events (SSE) blocking threads in mod_wsgi

Tags: multithreading, flask, mod-wsgi, wsgi, server-sent-events

My flask application implements SSE to push updates to each of my users. I.e. each of my users gets individual updates and therefore unique SSE connections. I deploy the application to mod_wsgi. Now mod_wsgi allows me to use a fixed number of threads (default 15) which are quickly all blocked when the number of users grows. This happens as the SSE connection are kept open and are therefore blocking the thread. Subsequent requests can't get in anymore and I get a `Script timed out before returning headers: wsgi.py` error.

My current workaround is to put a timer in my SSE generator and break it after a certain threshold. Still, with many users a fixed number of threads will still lead to blocked requests.

```
def stream():
    ...
    queue = memory.get(...)

    @stream_with_context
    def eventStream():
        try:
            start = time.time()
            while True:
                delta = start - time.time()
                if delta > app.config["SSE_TIMEOUT"]:
                    break
                # wait for source data to be available, then push it
                try:
                    entry = queue.get(
                        True, timeout=app.config["SSE_TIMEOUT"] - delta)
                except Empty:
                    break
                ev = ServerSentEvent(json.dumps(entry))
                yield ev.encode()
        finally:
            ...

    return Response(eventStream(), mimetype="text/event-stream")
```

I'd like top find a clean solution to be able to handle an arbitrary amount of users which are able to receive updates through SSE without blocking all threads in wsgi.

I posted this issue also on the mailing list of modwsgi: https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/modwsgi/-7he0l7KlU8